# C# get total memory used by an object

Tags: c#, memory-management, size

I have some custom types (the type cannot be serialized, so I cannot use `BinaryFormatter` and `MemoryStream` to get the bytes needed to hols this object) and I cannot use `Marshal.SizeOf()`. Is there other way to get the memory needed by a object? The object can be an instance of a custom type or an array of a custom type objects.

PS: It's not accurate to get the memory at the begining and at the end to obtain the memory needed because other processes runs in the background

Comment: The *variable*? assuming the type here is a reference-type - the variable will take exactly 4 or 8 bytes... You should replace "variable" with "object" (presumably) throughout.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sayse: "Is there other way to get the memory needed by a object?" I need to know how much memory occupies an object

Comment: @BudaGavril - For the majority of things you do in c# it shouldn't matter and you should just let it handle that itself.

Comment: For arrays and lists you can make an estimated calculation, for everything else you don't need to know.

Comment: The dupe lists five more question on this topic.

Comment: Indeed, the question that you've linked has an answer, but it's not marked as accepted. And for the arrays and lists, I cannot use estimated calculation because I have table variables (I use EF 1) and some records can have related table objects, some not... I cannot use third party tools(company policy)

Comment: So which 'object' did you want to measure? The EF object chache?

Comment: And really, Entity Framework 1?  That was more of a joke...

Comment: yeah, sorry, it was EF 3.5 and I want to know the size in bytes of an array of a custom type and the type has some table members among other strings and int's.

Comment: So it's not a single object but a (very complex) cluster. Still sounds like an XY problem. To convince us therwise, specify _why_ you need this.